# Python: find all sets of numbers inside a range where each set contains values that are x distance apart and don't exceed the range

Tags: python

Given a range, how could I find all sets of size x that meet the specific criteria of being at least x distance apart, not exceeding the range maximum?

If I wanted to find sets of three numbers that are 5 apart in a range of 30, I'd expect to get these values back:

```
[0,5,10]
[0,6,11]
[0,7,12]
..etc
[1,6,11]
[1,7,12]
[1,8,13]
..etc
```

I've looked at itertools, thinking there would be a quick solve there - but I'm not seeing a clear method.

I've tried to harvest all valid runs of numbers doing something like:

```
lst = [(x,x+5,x+10) for x in range(20)]
```

But that only get's me +5 values, not values that are +6, +7, etc. Remember, my distance requirement is a minimum.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

I'm new to Python and to Stackoverflow, so if my question is malformed or unclear or ridiculous, please go easy on me - I'm ready to clarify or continue researching as needed; I'm just stuck at the moment.  This seems like something that exists and I just can't find vs. something I need to try to cook up with nested iterations.

Thanks again!

Comment: I am clearly not getting what you are trying to do ? explain briefly in one line please

Comment: Good question, sounds like a challenge. Wait 45 seconds for Martijn Pieters to post an answer off the top of his head...

Comment: @Anmol_uppal : Given a range, I need to find all unique sets of three numbers inside that range that are at least 5 numbers apart.

Comment: Ok I am working on this, I guess you need nested for loops for this

Comment: @JoelCornett: "at least 5 apart"...

Comment: I'm torn - what's good manners here? I think @gboffi gave a workable solution first, but recursion seems more readable - wish I could mark two as as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> print [[x,y,z] for x in range(20) for y in range(x+5,20) for z in range(y+5,20)]
[[0, 5, 10], [0, 5, 11], [0, 5, 12], [0, 5, 13], ..., [8, 13, 19], [8, 14, 19], [9, 14, 19]]
>>>
```

*Addendum*

The OP asked for a general solution, the simplest form of a general solution is by code generation and this is my attempt at that

```
In [3]: def apart(top, delta, n):
    vars = ['x%d'%x for x in range(n)]
    code = '[['+','.join(vars)+'] for '+vars[0]+ ' in range(%d) '%top
    code = code + ' '.join(['for %s in range(%s+%d,%d)'%(xt,xl,d,t) for d,t in [(delta,top)] for xl,xt in zip(vars[:-1],vars[1:])])+']'
    return code
...: 

In [4]: apart(30,5,4)
Out[4]: '[[x0,x1,x2,x3] for x0 in range(30) for x1 in range(x0+5,30) for x2 in range(x1+5,30) for x3 in range(x2+5,30)]'

In [5]: apart(25,7,2)
Out[5]: '[[x0,x1] for x0 in range(25) for x1 in range(x0+7,25)]'

In [6]:
```

Comment: @BhargavRao You got SO close... Thank you for  the insight

Comment: for x in range(10) for y in range(x+5,15) for z in range(y+5,20)

Comment: This is very useful - thank you.  Any idea how I could scale this for 4 values, or 5 values?  The idea is that the user can define how many values are in a set; so this is pretty much a solve if the question is return x,y,z (which was my example, to be fair!) -- but if I'm finding 4, 5, or 6 values per set?  Could I still use a comprehension with a variable amount of variables somehow?  Anyway, thank you for this simple comprehension answer - it's very helpful.

Comment: @user3369105 I have generalized my answer to different parameters,

Comment: I think you have it, @gboffi.  Is code generation the only way to handle the generalization problem?  I've always been told to keep eval/exec to a minimum, but I don't know if I care that much for the sake of this problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
[(x,y,z) for x in range(20) for y in range(20) for z in range(20) if y>=x+5 and z>=y+5]
```

Had earlier posted it as comment

Comment: The condition will be false in over a half of cases…

Comment: @eumiro Yeah ... Any remedies?

Comment: It also prints (8, 16, 19), (8, 17, 19), (8, 18, 19), (8, 19, 19). Which should'nt

Comment: @BhargavRao - yes, limit the ranges, just like gboffi and stark did.

Comment: @eumiro Hadn't thought of that earlier. I had posted it before everyone, after which they managed to improvise on it. So I didn't want to take their idea. Sorry... :(

Comment: @BhargavRao it works now. I tried that which was is comments before. Sorry! That upvote is from me

Answer (score 3):

You could throw recursion at the problem (this could be prettied up a bit):

```
def jump(n, min_gap, right_bound, so_far=None):
    if so_far is None: so_far = []
    if n == 0:
        yield so_far
    else:
        min_x0 = 0 if not so_far else so_far[-1] + min_gap
        for i in range(min_x0, right_bound):
            for child in jump(n-1, min_gap, right_bound, so_far+[i]):
                yield child
```

which gives

```
>>> pprint.pprint(list(jump(3, 1, 5)))
[[0, 1, 2],
 [0, 1, 3],
 [0, 1, 4],
 [0, 2, 3],
 [0, 2, 4],
 [0, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 4],
 [1, 3, 4],
 [2, 3, 4]]
>>> pprint.pprint(list(jump(3, 2, 5)))
[[0, 2, 4]]
```

and matches @gboffi's results:

```
>>> list(jump(3, 5, 20)) == [[x,y,z] for x in range(20) for y in range(x+5,20) for z in range(y+5,20)]
True
>>> list(jump(4,5,30)) == eval(apart(30,5,4))
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
r=[] 
for a in range(20):
    for b in range(20):
        for c in range(20):
            if b>=a+5 and c>=a+10 and c>=b+5:
                r.append((a,b,c))    
print(r)
```

Comment: The condition will be false in most cases…

Comment: It works, but if it keeps iterating for `a > 9` , then it is not quite as efficient as the proposal of gboffi and stark.

Comment: Since we're looking at sets of numbers, there's no need to iterate over all the numbers in every loop -- some of them will have been covered in previous iterations.

Answer (score 0):

```
def intervals(n, min_, max_):
    if n < 2:
        yield from ([i] for i in range(min_, max_ + 1))
    else:
        remaining = max_ - ((n - 1) * min_)
        for i in range(min_, remaining + 1):
            for item in intervals(n - 1, min_, max_ - i):
                yield [i] + item

def calculate(size, lower, upper, min_interval):
    for item in intervals(size, min_interval, upper - lower):
        t = [item[0]]
        for v in item[1:]:
            t.append(v + item[-1])

        yield t
```

Comment: This is interesting, but it leaves out some of the expected answers - like [0,6,11] for instance.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I misread OP's criteria. Missed the "at least". Fixing.